# Can we ask for resume review here in The Workplace?

Tags: discussion, support

I don't know if it is allowed to ask for review of resume here at workplace.
So is it good to ask for that here just like  in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for codes written by peers.

Comment: "I don't know if it is allowed to ask for review of resume here at workplace." - it's not allowed.

Comment: Invite me to a chat room, and post your resume there. I will review it for you. You are, of course, free to invite other users too.

Comment: Why downvotes ? If not a good feature request question then it is atleast  informative for the users

Answer (score 9):

The [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site is a site that went through the [Area-51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) process.

If you believe the ResumeReview site is needed then start that process, or see if somebody has already started one.

Answer (score 6):

If a new ResumeReview.stackechange.com site were created, I'd be happy to help review some resumes, cover letters, and CVs for folks.

But it shouldn't clutter up The Workplace. This would be the wrong site.

Comment: "Clutter" is a suspect word. StackOverflow is something like 100x or 1000x bigger than us and remains pretty functional even though 99% of the questions are about languages and technology I don't know. Sure, let there be another kind of question on workplace.SE, if you don't like it filter it out. Why not.

Comment: @djechlin disagree, SO is so big that it has quite some problems, the close queue is always at 7k~10k pending. Its so big that you can 't follow the last question list, you follow by tags, which means quite some are not followed. The SE.doc iseven worst on this point, some has very clean documentation, others don't. Because no one can cover that many tags which involves differents languages, techs, ...

Comment: I think "clutter" is the right word. I don't want to see The Workplace cluttered with "please review my Resume" requests. It would get out of hand very fast. Put that in it's own forum and interested people can go there.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see this as practical for the workplace, even for a "resume review" site as we have a code review site.  Ask 5 people for advice on a resume, you'll get 10 different answers.  Not only is there variance from field to field, there's cultural and even regional variations that, IMO, would leave any querents more confused than they were when they arrived.

Comment: I agree.  I don't think a ResumeReview site would be all that compelling.  Reviewing code is a lot more fun than reviewing a resume.

Comment: Plus, reviewing a resume requires a lot of personal knowledge about the applicant and the company that we can't possibly know.

Answer (score 3):

We would be flooded with these and I for one am not interested in reviewing resumes. Terrible idea.

Comment: I can understand @Kilisi